# Querying Realm to populate numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt with Multiple Sections using Realm and Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

I'm new to Realm and Swift, and to this site for that matter, so please forgive me if my question is poorly worded, but I will do my best. Here goes...

Basically I'm trying to build a Gym App. The idea is to allow the user to type out the title of their workout and to select a day of the week from a Picker View, to assign to that particular workout.

With that said, I'm having some trouble figuring out how to code the numberOfRowsInSection function so that it returns the number of rows based on the number of objects in that particular section. In other words, to return the number of rows based on the number of workouts that I have stored for that particular day of the week.

I'm also having a similar problem with the cellForRowAt function. I'm trying to figure out how to       populate the cells with titles of the workouts, based on section/day of the week.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import SwipeCellKit

class WorkoutsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {


    let realm = try! Realm()

    var workouts : Results<Workouts>?
    var days : Results<WeekDays>?

    var daysOfWeek : [String] = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednsday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

    let picker = UIPickerView()


    @IBOutlet weak var WorkoutsTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        WorkoutsTableView.delegate = self
        WorkoutsTableView.dataSource = self

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self

        loadCategories()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        tableView.rowHeight = 80.0

        //Populate based on the # of workouts in each day.

        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        button.setTitle(daysOfWeek[section], for: .normal)

        return button
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell.delegate = self

        //Populate with titles of workouts based on section/day of the week.
        //cell.textLabel?.text = days?[indexPath.row].workouts[indexPath.row].name


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {

        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in



        }

        // customize the action appearance
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete-icon")

        return [deleteAction]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
        var options = SwipeOptions()
        options.expansionStyle = .destructive
        return options
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }



    @IBAction func AddWorkoutButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var textField = UITextField()

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Workout", message: "Please name your workout...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Workout", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
                //Add workout to database
            let newWorkout = Workouts()
            let dow = WeekDays()

            dow.day = self.daysOfWeek[self.picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
            newWorkout.name = textField.text!
            dow.workouts.append(newWorkout)

            self.save(newDay: dow)
        }

        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Muscle Group"
            textField = alertTextField
            alertTextField.inputView = self.picker
        }

        alert.addAction(addAction)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func save(newDay: WeekDays){
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(newDay)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error saving workout \(error)")
        }
        WorkoutsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func loadCategories(){
        days = realm.objects(WeekDays.self)
        workouts = realm.objects(Workouts.self)
        WorkoutsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func EditWorkout(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    }

}

extension WorkoutsViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return daysOfWeek[row]
    }



}
```

{

```
class Workouts : Object {
            @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
            var parentDay = LinkingObjects(fromType: WeekDays.self, property: "workouts")
        }




class WeekDays : Object {
    @objc dynamic var day : String = ""
    let workouts = List<Workouts>()
}
```

Comment: Can you share your data model so we can help you better?

Comment: I added the data model. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for providing us with your models. As I see you already have a list of `Workouts` on your `WeekDay` elements, so your query to populate your Table View is simplified by this.

First things first. I recommend you to change your declaration of the results in your controller to use the following

```
class WorkoutsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var days : Results<WeekDays>!
    // ... rest of the implementation 
}
```

This way you can void the optional handling for the table view datasource and delegate methods.

That being said, you only need to query the `WeekDay` objects on the view controller. I usually do this on the `viewDidLoad`:

```
days = realm.objects(WeekDays.self)
```

The associated `workouts` are loaded automatically and associated to each of the days you're getting from the database, on the `days` array.

Based on your requirement you can create the required number of sections for your table view like the following:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.days.count
}
```

That code will create as many section as the size of the `days` array. The next task is to provide the number of rows in the given section. This is almost immediate because we already have an array of the `WorkOuts` objects on the day:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let day = days[section]
    return day.workouts.count
}
```

At this point we already have provided the number of sections in the table view (days) and the number of rows for each section (workouts associated to the corresponding day).

After this each cell can be configured based on the `days` array information (don't forget this is an array of `WeekDays` objects, each one containing an array of `workouts`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    cell.delegate = self

    // Populate with titles of workouts based on section/day of the week.
    cell.textLabel?.text = days[indexPath.section].workouts[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
}
```

The key here is you must obtain the `WeekDays` object (by getting the object at the index `indexPath.section` from the `days` array) and then getting the Workout details by getting the `Workouts` object at index `indexPath.row` from the weekday's array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate the help, but what about the numberOfRowsInSection function? How can I retrieve the appropriate number of rows/workouts for each section/day-of-the-week?

Also, instead of returning self.days.count, why can't I just return 7, since I already know that there are 7 days in a week and I don't want to show duplicate days of the week, I just want the workout to match under the appropriate day.

Does it make more sense if I go ahead and create a two-dimensional array instead?

Once again, thank you for you help.

Comment: That's a good question @RapsIn4 I updated my answer to address the `numberOfRowsInSection` part. It is a good practice to delegate all the logic for counting, accesing and processing the information to the database. If, for instance, your database only contains 6 days (or any other number than 7) then the app would crash because the index might be out of bounds. I recommend you to use Realm or any other database as a single source of truth.

Comment: As an additional advise, if you already know you have only 7 days on the week, or you get more results, you can query for that purposes. My guess is after some time the user will get more than a few workouts so you can delimit the query by date. Check that on the docs for Query - Filtering: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries

Comment: Thanks @Orlando ! That helped. I do have one more question though...

When I save a new workout, I call WorkoutsTableView.reloadData(), which updates all of the titles for all of my sections to the same title as my last entry. 

Should I just reload the rows instead of reloading both the rows and the sections? 

Much appreciated!

Comment: That's another god question. I recommend you to check on the docs for "Collection Notifications" on the docs: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications Basically Realm can manage that for you too. The notification listener you have as an example there can reload, insert or delete the table view cells as needed. That's why I advised you to use Realm as your source of truth: It can hadle this changes with minimal developer effort. If you run into any difficult with notif. you can open another question to address those issues. Meanwhile, if my answer is useful, please mark it as accepted.