# How to effectively load the properties string for all rows of data from realm into UILabels in a UITableView

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, properties, realm

Within my realm I have `RealmClassA`, with many rows of information that the user can successfully add to whilst running in simulator.

I am trying to read the data from realm (technical term `Query`?!) to display some of the data into a `TableViewController` within a `customCell` that houses many `UILabels`. The customCell is of type `TableViewCell`.

For examples sake I have included only some of the properties and labels.

I would like to display the data from `propertyA` column, into the UIlabel's in alphabetical order, alongside the other data in `propertyB` column for that row entry. See image below.

[image: Rough design of what is currently on Storyboard and What I would like to display during app run]

The `TableViewController` is;

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
      
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
        //After solving this question, this numberOfSections return will return the count of the number of unique strings that the propertyB column that RealmClassA houses. 
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
      
  return realm.objects(RealmClassA.self).count
        // this DOES return a number of cells that matches the number of entries (rows) in RealmClassA. 

    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reusableCellID", for: indexPath)

    // this is where I have hit a brick wall and guidance is needed.        

        return cell
    }
}
```

The `customCell` is of type `TableViewCell`;

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var propertyAGoesHere: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var propertyBGoesHere: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var propertyCGoesHere: UILabel!
//etc.
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I am able to count the number of entries in the Output using the following;

```
print("The number of RealmClassA records in memory is",realm.objects(RealmClassA.self).count)
```

It prints out `The number of RealmClassA in memory is 10`

When I attempt to print just the names of the stings in propertyA column;

```
    let allEntriesArray = allEntriesList.map{$0.PropertyA}
            
    print("Querying all propertyA entries in realm \(allEntriesArray)")
```

it prints out

```
Querying all propertyA entries in realm LazyMapSequence<Results<RealmClassA>, String>(_base: Results<RealmClassA> <0x7fd2f8cb4f20> (
    [0] RealmClassA {
        propertyA = Random Words for Filler
        propertyB = More Random words to fill the property information;
        //etc. 
    },
// this repeats for all entries in the RealmClassA.
```

**Help needed with**

1. HOW to effectively access the data from realm to display in the table view. I'm clearly nearly there, as I can display the correct number of cells for the number of entries in RealmClassA.
2. Whether I have over complicated something along the line.

I have used the following sources as help to no avail.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WOd6GVPMb0

[UITableView with Multiple Sections using Realm and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728938/uitableview-with-multiple-sections-using-realm-and-swift/38797693#38797693)

[Querying Realm to populate numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt with Multiple Sections using Realm and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061507/querying-realm-to-populate-numberofrowsinsection-and-cellforrowat-with-multiple)

[How to access properties of an object returned from primary key query in Realm Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091877/how-to-access-properties-of-an-object-returned-from-primary-key-query-in-realm-s)

And I have scoured the Realm.io documentation here

https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-list-new-superpowers-array-primitives/

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started in the List section

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html

**update**

Changing any instances of ‘PropertyA’ to ‘propertyA’ throughout.

Main question for clarity.
How to display all data from one column in saved in realm, in an alphabetical order inside a tableview cells’ UILabels.

Apologies for the length of post, I see a lot of questions commented with people asking for all the information so I have done my utmost!

**update 2**

Removing unnecessary information for clarity after answer posted

Comment: Wow - that's a lot of info. Is there one specific question? Can you edit down the question a bit so it's more focused? Also, `allEntriesList.map{$0.PropertyA}` is going to be a problem as your Realm object doesn't have a `.PropertyA` but it does have `.propertyA`. Also *HOW to effectively access the data from realm to display in the table view* is just a matter of getting the object for that row from your tableView dataSource `let realmObject = dataSource[row]` and then get the property `let someData = realmObject.property` and then assign it to the textField `cell.textField.text = someData`

Comment: Thanks Jay. I have updated my question to include the main question for clarity. Where specifically would I put my `realmObject = dataSource[row]` please? For me, would it be `let RealmClassA = dataSource[row]` , `let propertyAList = RealmClassA.propertyA` and in the UILabel, `cell.textField.text = propertyAList`

Comment: It would be in the `tableView(_ tableView:cellForRowAt` function, right after the cell is instantiated `let cell = tableView.`. It's kinda just the way to populate cells - get the associated data from the dataSource, and then populate the cell's fields, images etc from that. And yes to the rest of your comment, that's the correct sequence, although don't use capital letters for variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jay's help plus this website;
https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/,
I found I was missing `as! customCell` from the end of the `cellForRowAt` func.

Here is how it should look if anyone is looking at this further down the line.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reusableCellID", for: indexPath) as! customCell

        let itemsToDisplay = realm.objects(RealmClassA.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "propertyA")[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.propertyADisaplyLabel?.text = itemsToDisplay.propertyA
        cell.propertyBDisplayLabel?.text = itemsToDisplay.propertyB
        cell.propertyCDisplayLabel?.text = itemsToDisplay.propertyC
        

        return cell
    }
```

**EDIT**

Setting up a tableView dataSource on macOS - iOS is very similar. This sets up a dataSource with 10 objects. This example is really to show a proper use of the dataSource.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    
    var dataArray = [String]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: NSTableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        for i in 0...9 {
            let s = "row_\(i)"
            self.dataArray.append(s)
        }
        
        self.myTableView.delegate = self
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return self.dataArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
       let identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("MyCellView")
       guard let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else {return nil}
    
       cell.textField?.stringValue = self.dataArray[row]
    }
```

Note the NSTableCellView (Table Cell View) identifier is set to MyCellView.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. However, this is not going to be a good solution in general. You *never* want to hit a database during tableView delegate functions. Tableviews are designed to be fast and lightweight and they should use the minimal amount of code to update the UI. This `let itemsToDisplay = realm.objects(` is going to cause it to be laggy and perform poorly as it's pulling data from disk. You should use that function to populate the tableView dataSource (typically an array) and pull from that array (which is in memory, not in disk) when populating tableView cells.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I've removed `itemsToDisplay ...` from the cellForRowAt override func, now used `let itemsToDisplay = Array(realm.objects(RealmClassA.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "propertyA")` below `import RealmSwift` get error: Use of unresolved identifier 'realm'. When placed below `class TableViewController:...` I get the error: Cannot use instance member 'realm' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available. When put in viewDidLoad method, the `cell.propetyADisplayLabel?.text etc` for all properties gets error `Use of unresolved identifier 'itemToDisplay'

Comment: Still very junior when it comes to Swift and Xcode, knowing where to put the code itself is normally the learning curve for myself. I'm assuming I've used the incorrect method to create the array, or I've tried to create the Array in the wrong View Controller entirely?

Comment: Your going to want to set up a class var that's an 'array' which will act as the dataSource for the tableView. While an 'array' is what we want, any object that 'acts' like an array is also suitable. The Realm Results class 'acts' like an array. The issue with this `itemsToDisplay = Array(realm.objects` is that Realm objects are live, and lazily loaded - meaning that as things change in Realm, they are automatically reflected in the Results object. Casting it to an array 'breaks' that link. Additionally it will load ALL objects into memory which could be a lot - so use a results object.

Comment: Hi Jay. Would I set this up in a completely new ViewController? I can't figure where to create the array in the tableViewController without hitting errors.

Comment: It's not best practice here to modify an answer but you really seem to be struggling so I edited your answer and included the code to create the dataSource, populate it and then display it in a tableView.

Comment: Thanks for persevering, Jay. I've created a new tableViewController from your answer to try to make an array from the data in realm. I can see how this would help reduce disc reading and save time, but I am still uncertain exactly *how* to populate the dataArray with the information from Realm. Im getting errors every which way I attempt to populate the dataArray. I'm sure this should is a simple process, and there is probably something small I've omitted, and in the future I'll look back at this and wonder how i was ever stuck! 3 more rep and I could ask away from public eyes!

Comment: I am not sure where you are stuck exactly. Reading data from Realm is covered in the [Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started) and in particular it's a single line of code as shown [Here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries) with `let dogs = realm.objects(Dog.self)`. The only difference is that dogs needs to be a class var `var allDogs: Results<Dog>?`. That allDogs class var would be your tableView dataSource. If you're still stuck, post another question with details and the code you've attempted.